# Entity framework repository pattern with null value property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I will try to explain my situation. I'm using entity framework 6 Code First. I've created my models, let me show you few of them for example:

```
 public class User
{
    [Required, Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(20), MinLength(8)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; } 
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required, UniqProp]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; } 
}
```

And my Role:

```
public enum RoleType
{
    Admin,
    User,
    Courier
}

public class Role
{
    [Required, Key]
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public RoleType? RoleType { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> User { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see I use one to many relationship between User and Role. Few users can have one role - seems to be correctly. Entity Framework creates relations correct, but because I've got confused I make some relations using fluent api, you can see it bellow:

```
public class TheatreContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Play> Plays { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasRequired<Role>(user => user.Role)
            .WithMany(role => role.User)
            .HasForeignKey(user => user.RoleId);
    }
}
```

Well, anyway it works fine.
So I've created repository pattern that helps me to make some actions with DB. It is generic and I have to say that in repositiry constructor I create new context. That means when my repository just created in each table I do not have any entities local.
Here is my problem: when I add new user, for example, I just have to attach UserId and after that entity framework should return me value of Role property when I ask it, shouldn't it? When I add a new user and save changes in DB my new user in dbSet has null value of Role property local and in DataBase too. So when I use Find method or another query to receive User this property anyway returns me null. But when I make query in debug mode in context to show me Roles in DB(Roles table), Find method or whatever returns me User with not null Role property value. Also I mentioned that after disposing my repository and creating a new one everything works fine. If I'm right the problem is in local data because I do not have any roles Local and that's why I can't give me the role for the User.
In conclusion I have to say that I'm confused! I know that after reading this post with my "perfect" english you are confused too;)
Please help someone!

Here I add two new users and commit changes(save changes in db):

```
             var repo = new TheatreRepository<User>();
        var repo2 = new TheatreRepository<Role>();
        var userRoleId = repo2.GetAll().First(role => role.RoleType == RoleType.User).RoleId;
        var newUser = new User
                          {
                              UserId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                              City = "Minsk",
                              RoleId = userRoleId,
                              FirstName = "Slavik",
                              Email = "SlavaMinsk@gmail.com",
                              Password = "dsas1qsqda",
                              LastName = "Fedorov"
                         };
        repo.Add(newUser);
        repo.Commit();
        var user = repo.GetById(newUser.UserId);
        var userAgain = repo.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(user1 => user1.UserId == newUser.UserId);
```

Both of queries returned newUser with null Role property value. GetById - Find method of DbSet, GetAll - returns me DbSet

Comment: You need to set the value of Role when you add a new record for User, if that's what you're asking?

Comment: Not exactly. I need to get Role value from User after adding it to database

Comment: Do you have a particular linq query to show us?

Comment: You can see it above. Hope this is what you asked. I added two users and while Commit I saved them to database. Then I display user.Role value for two equals queries for one user

Comment: Eh.. I'm afraid it's too distorted/not zoomed in enough. You can always just paste the code (neatly) here (in your question, just edit it)

Comment: Off topic: Please get the RoleId for user inside a var before creating any user.  `var userRoleId = repo2.GetAll().First(role => role.RoleType == RoleType.User).RoleId; ` and then  `newUser2 = new User { ..... RoleId = userRoleId; ...... }; `

Comment: Razvan Dumitru, I did it above. Anyway it returns me null value of Role property